# Using the getData or beforeGetData event to modify data in CKEditor results in old data

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.4.1 with YUI.

The thing with YUI is that if you hover, click or interact with any element on the page, it generates and adds an ID attribute to that element.

It also does the same for CKEditor's elements.

What I need to do is to remove the id attributes using the `getData` event.

I am attempting to remove the id attributes like so:

```
editor.on('getData', function(e){

    e.editor.undoManager.lock();

    var ids = e.editor.element.find('[id]');

    for(i = 0; i < ids.count(); i++){
        ids.getItem(i).removeAttribute('id');
    }

    e.data.dataValue = e.editor.getData(true);
    e.editor.undoManager.unlock();
});
```

It seems, for some reason, the call to `getData()` in the event handler is not getting the latest version of the data, instead, it is producing data from before the id attributes were removed.

```
<p>test
<a href="test.com">aaa</a>test2
<a href="sss.com">sss</a>test</p>
<p id="yui_3_16_0_1_1401707830563_1402">test asdf</p>
<p id="yui_3_16_0_1_1401707830563_1403">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">link</a>
</p>
```

I also tried using the `beforeGetData` event, but the same problem occurs:

```
editor.on('beforeGetData', function(e){

    e.editor.undoManager.lock();

    var ids = e.editor.element.find('[id]');

    for(i = 0; i < ids.count(); i++){
        ids.getItem(i).removeAttribute('id');
    }

    e.editor.undoManager.unlock();
});
```

After some more experimenting, I noticed the following:

- `getSnapshot()` returns the latest data, but it also causes some problems, because attributes such as `data-cke-saved-href` are not removed.
- It looks like the data returned by `getData()` is created immediately once there's a change. Therefore, modifications to content using the `beforeGetData` and `getData` events do not appear to work.

Is there anyway to ensure that `getData()` gets the latest version of the data? Is there anyway to force `getData()` to update its data?

Answer (score -1):

Try to give a chance for options allowedContent  and disallowedContent. See 'How to Allow Everything Except...' in http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content

Comment: Please add some more explanation instead of posting a link-only answer. Links break, and we want Stack Overflow to remain a good source of information regardless of whether links posted here stop working.